# How to generate JFree 3D pie chart with drop shadow effect like 3D bar chart

Tags: jfreechart

When I generate 3D bar chart, drop shadow is visible.but the same effect is not seen in 3D pie chart. Which method can be used for it. pls help. thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this: plot.setDarkerSides(true);

Comment: Thanks Daisy. It was indeed very helpful